# Unable to use .delete attribute to a canvas

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

Alright, so I'm trying to delete a canvas once a requirement is met but I get this error:
I wish that when herox gets to the value of 700 that the background changes and I think I can only do that once the old background is deleted.

```
line 56, in <module>
    backgroundcanvas.delete(ALL)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'delete'
```

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image



root = Tk()
root.title("Game")

heroc = None
backgroundcanvas = None

speed = 10

def ChangeMap():
    heropos = canvas.coords(heroc)
    herox = heropos[0]
    heroy = heropos[1]
    if herox == 700:
        print("requirement met")
        backgroundcanvas.delete("all")
        backgroundcanvas.create_image(350, 200, image="background2.png")

def Move_hero(event):
    global heroc
    if event.keysym == "Up":
        canvas.move(heroc, 0, -speed)
    if event.keysym == 'Down':
        canvas.move(heroc, 0, speed)
    if event.keysym == 'Right':
        ChangeMap()
        canvas.move(heroc, speed, 0)
    if event.keysym == 'Left':
        canvas.move(heroc, -speed, 0)
        print(canvas.coords(heroc))


canvas = Canvas(root, bg="black", width=700, height=400)
canvas.pack()

heroc = None
backgroundcanvas = None

background = PhotoImage(file="background.png")
background2 = PhotoImage(file="background2.png")
backgroundcanvas = canvas.create_image(350,200,image=background)


character = PhotoImage(file="hero.png")
heroc = canvas.create_image(30, 260 ,image=character)

canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Up>', Move_hero)
canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Down>', Move_hero)
canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Left>', Move_hero)
canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Right>', Move_hero)

root.mainloop()
```

If the images and other things from the code are needed I will add them :)

Comment: Can't you just clear the canvas `clearRect(x, y, canvas.width, canvas.height)`.

Comment: I need to clear the image in it, so clearRect won't do the job here.

Comment: `backgroundcanvas` is just the ID of the object on the canvas, which is an integer. You should probably use `canvas.delete(backgroundcanvas)` and then `backgroundcanvas = canvas.create_image(...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is telling you exactly what's wrong: you're trying to call `delete("all")` on an integer -- it's the same error as if you did `42.delete("all")`.

The reason is that `backgroundcanvas` is an integer -- a canvas id -- and integers don't have a `delete` method. Instead, you need to be calling the `delete` method of the canvas. If you want to delete everything then you would do `canvas.delete("all")`, and if you want to delete just the background you would do `canvas.delete(backgroundcanvas`.

The same is true for the following line where you try to call `create_image` on `backgroundcanvas`. You need to call it on the actual canvas widget.